# Enrich values of object

Tags: java, frameworks

Let's say I have a Person-Object a with firstname = Ronald and name = null.

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String name;
}
```

And I need to enrich the empty values with values of another object..
Person b with firstname = "Matt" and Lastname = "Kingley"

So the result should be a Person with firstname : Ronald but lastname "Kingley"

What is the best way to do this?
Are there any good framewroks for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, could you explain a little further?`if(personA.firstname == null)
    personA.firstname = personB.firstname;
if(personA.name == null)
    personA.name = personB.name;`

Comment: Yeah, But this is just a simple example. I want to make it generic, so that for example if you have a class with 50 fields that you don't have to it for every field.

Comment: Why not just start off with initial values for all the fields affected?

Comment: I have the same question and looking for a generic solution. Like with a Map where you loop through the keys and compare the values for each key in the objects, taking the value that isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

I would just implement a method inside the class that handles this.
However, the purposes of this are pretty unclear, are you trying to fill in the name in case it wasn't filled?

If so just write into the constructor that take sonly one parameter that you want to assign the lastname to a constant (or something else?)

```
public Person(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.name = "DefaultName";
}
```

Otherwise you could implement a merge method (still unclear question so this might not be what you're looking for):

```
public void mergePersonIfNull(Person person){
    if (this.lastName == null)
        this.lastName = person.getLastName(); //Assuming you have getters
    //same for firstname
}
```

What's more, if you're not making use of the null comparison, removes it and force the replacement.

Anyway, maybe precise your usages and I'll be more precise cause I'm still unsure I understood the question.